# SCALA - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scalactic/TripleEquals

Tags: java, scala, scalatest

I am running some Scala Tests (scala-lang - 2.12.3, scalatest - 3.0.1) building using ant with java 1.8 and without any IDE. Initially, when I ran the tests I got the error *scala.xml.Elem - the object xml is not a member of package scala*. I resolved this error by adding following in my build script

> scalactic_2.12-3.0.2.jar, scala-reflect.jar, scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar, scala-compiler.jar along with scala-library.jar and scalatest_2.11-3.0.1.jar

after adding these the build is compiling with some warnings like

> warning: object JavaConversions in package collection is deprecated
> (since 2.12.0): use JavaConverters

but when its running the tests its throwing following error

```
run:
     [exec] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scalactic/TripleEquals
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
     [exec]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
     [exec]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [exec]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
     [exec]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
     [exec]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [exec]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [exec]     at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
     [exec] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scalactic.TripleEquals
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [exec]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [exec]     ... 25 more
```

Any suggestions what I am missing.

Comment: Legacy, the command is "ant test all"

Comment: Do you have [scalactic](https://www.scalactic.org/) as a dependency?

Comment: Yes scalactic_2.12-3.0.2.jar

Comment: According to `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scalactic.TripleEquals` looks like it was not fetched successfully. Please make sure it is there.

Comment: It's worth noting this may be related to **JDK-8302483**, a work-around *should* disable that extra field validation using `-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true`